# Why does IPTraf show multiple MAC addresses for my interfaces?

Tags: ip, mac-address

Hopefully a simple question with a simple answer.

I *thought* each NIC had a single MAC address. However, as can be seen from the [IPTraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/) output below, I have multiple MAC addresses for both my `eth0` and `wlan0` interfaces.

Why do I have multiple MAC addresses?

```
+----------- PktsIn --------------------- IP In ------------- BytesIn ----------------- InRate ------------ PktsOut ------------------- IP Out ------------- BytesOut ------------- OutRate ----------------+
| Ethernet HW addr: 0021cccbeed0 on eth0                                                                                                                                                                    |
| +        3094                        0                   1355136                      2.0                 3286                         0                   894518                   5.4                   |
| Ethernet HW addr: 1cbdb98d4053 on eth0                                                                                                                                                                    |
| +        3227                        0                    888314                      5.4                 3111                         0                  1359575                   2.0                   |
| Ethernet HW addr: ffffffffffff on eth0                                                                                                                                                                    |
| +         170                        0                     21922                      0.0                    0                         0                        0                   0.0                   |
| Ethernet HW addr: 74e5439d621b on wlan0                                                                                                                                                                   |
| +           6                        0                       312                      0.0                  104                         0                    15380                   0.0                   |
| Ethernet HW addr: 01005e000001 on eth0                                                                                                                                                                    |
| +          10                        0                       460                      0.0                    0                         0                        0                   0.0                   |
| Ethernet HW addr: 01005e00000c on wlan0                                                                                                                                                                   |
| +           4                        0                       184                      0.0                    0                         0                        0                   0.0                   |
| Ethernet HW addr: 00042022bc60 on eth0                                                                                                                                                                    |
| +           0                        0                         0                      0.0                   24                         0                     1440                   0.0                   |
| Ethernet HW addr: 01005e0000fb on eth0                                                                                                                                                                    |
| +          33                        0                      6928                      0.0                    0                         0                        0                   0.0                   |
| Ethernet HW addr: 6c626db33eea on eth0                                                                                                                                                                    |
| +          22                        0                      1844                      0.0                   53                         0                    11781                   0.0                   |
| Ethernet HW addr: 885395dbb6b1 on eth0                                                                                                                                                                    |
| +           0                        0                         0                      0.0                   25                         0                     7058                   0.0                   |
| Ethernet HW addr: 01005e000002 on wlan0                                                                                                                                                                   |
| +           1                        0                        32                      0.0                    0                         0                        0                   0.0                   |
| Ethernet HW addr: 01005e7ffffa on wlan0                                                                                                                                                                   |
| +          36                        0                     14620                      0.0                    0                         0                        0                   0.0                   |
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that those are the MACs of devices talking TO your eth0 and wlan0 respectively, not of your own devices.